# Prestashop 1.7 - Override Symfony form constraints

Tags: symfony, prestashop, symfony4, prestashop-1.7

### Context

I'm trying to change the constraint for the Product name attribute and increase the field length to 300 characters.

### Issue

In the `src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Product/ProductInformation.php`, I can change :

```php
->add('name', TranslateType::class, [
    'type' => FormType\TextType::class,
    'options' => [
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\Regex([
                'pattern' => '/[<>;=#{}]/',
                'match' => false,
            ]),
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Length(['min' => 3, 'max' => 128]),
        ],
    ],
])
```

to

```php
->add('name', TranslateType::class, [
    'type' => FormType\TextType::class,
    'options' => [
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\Regex([
                'pattern' => '/[<>;=#{}]/',
                'match' => false,
            ]),
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Length(['min' => 3, 'max' => 300]),
        ],
    ],
])
```

And.. it works. But what will happen if PrestaShop is updated. I need a more elegant way to do it.

### Update #1

There is PR on the official PrestaShop Github repository. I'm waiting for an answer : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/23977

Comment: Something like the `Services` ? https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/services/

Answer (score 0):

The classic way is override the model, in this case /override/classes/Product.php

On static $definition you change name field, size attribute from 128 to 300

Comment: Thanks but I have already done that. My issue concerns the length constraint..